# How did I vote?

Tags: support, voting

Now that I have your attention, I wanted to ask if it’s possible to access your voting history? I understand I can’t see **how people vote**, but can I see **how I’ve voted**?

If not can we make this a new feature?

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality already exists. You can check how **you** have voted, but obviously not how others have voted.

To check your votes:

1. Click on your profile image (on a desktop browser it’s towards the top right of the window)
2. By default you should be on the **Activity** tab, but if you’re not, select it
3. If you look below the Reputation and Badges section you’ll see a number of tabs: Summary, Answers, Questions, etc.
4. Click on the Votes tab (usually the last one)
5. This will show you all your votes, including:

   - total votes cast
   - a list of all posts and how long ago you voted on them (if in the last 48hrs) or the date you voted for them (if longer than 48hrs)
   - a link to the post you voted on
   - options to sort the list (e.g. all, upvote, downvote, etc)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.